# <blockquote> tags in iTextSharp pdf

Tags: itext

I am converting HTML to List using XMLWorker, the indentation (using blockquote tags) not appears in pdf. I have tried creating List with HTMLWorker but the result is same. Is there any way to preserve indentation (when using blockquote tag in HTML for indentation) in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The `blockquote` and `li` do not have indentation to "preserve", its just that almost every browser (if not all) choose to indent them by default. This is an individual choice made by every browser vendor, just as Netscape choose to use grey as the default body background color in the 90's. Any text formatting that you see iText doing is its own "default style" and anything that differs from your expectations you'll need to manually change.

When I try to run a `blockquote` through the XMLWorker version 5.4.0 I don't see anything and its not on the list of [supported HTML tags](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html). Do you have it further wrapped in a `SPAN` or some other tag? Can you post a sample?

When I run an `OL/LI` combination through 5.4.0 I see that iText makes them indented. Can you post a sample that doesn't indent? One quick fix would be to apply a simple margin to the `UL/OL` such `<ol style="margin-left:100px;">`